# Closing the Popup in Android

Tags: android, android-widget, popup

I have the following function which calls a popup from a menu button click. It has an ok button to close the popup. But the `onclick` function is not initiated on a button press. Also, I need to close the popup when the back button is pressed.

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_popup, null, false),400,440, true);

    pw.showAtLocation(lv, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    View popupView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_popup, null, false);
    Button close = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.okbutton);
    close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(View popupView) {
        pw.dismiss();
      }
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

currently you are passing different instance of View to `PopupWindow` and try to find Button in difference instance use same instance which u have passed in PopupWindow to find button . Change your code as :

```
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.about_popup, null, false);
  final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(popupView,400,440, true);

  pw.showAtLocation(lv, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    Button close = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.okbutton);
    close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(View popupView) {
        pw.dismiss();
      }
    });
```

second way is use `PopupWindow` instance to find Button on Current Window inside of inflating layout again for button as :

```
Button close = (Button) pw.findViewById(R.id.okbutton);
close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View popupView) {
            pw.dismiss();
          }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, I got where it was wrong.
changed to View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_popup, null, false);

Answer (score 1):

```
CustomDialogClass cdd = new CustomDialogClass(this,
                "Internet Connection Error",
                "Sorry, no internet connection.Feeds cannot be refreshed",
                "Alert");
        cdd.show();

public class CustomDialogClass extends Dialog implements
    android.view.View.OnClickListener {
String txtTitle, txtText, txtType;
Button btn;
TextView alertText;
ImageView imgVw;

public CustomDialogClass(Context context, String title, String text,
        String type) {
    super(context);
    txtTitle = title;
    txtText = text;

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.alert_layout);
    imgVw = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iconImgview);

    alertText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AlertText);
    alertText.setText(txtText);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dismis_dialog);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change This

```
  View popupView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_popup, null, false);
    Button close = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.okbutton);
```

to

```
 Button close = (Button) pw.findViewById(R.id.okbutton);
```